# Why can't I import .babylon files from blender using Babylon.js?

Tags: javascript, blender, babylonjs

I have been trying to import a blender file to a html file using babylon.js, but whenever I open the file in chrome, instead of the scene, there is just a loading icon. I don't know where the loading icon came from. The scene works the way it is supposed to when I drag and drop it into the babylon sandbox. I have also been having trouble with importing textures, so I thought the problem might have something to do with referencing the files in the html document.

Comment: Do you see any logs in console?

Comment: This might sound really stupid but where is the console?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+J https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I looked and it said     XMLHttpRequest cannot load,     and requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I got it fixed, thank you for your help. I just needed to go to terminal and disable web security

Comment: @Johnn feel free to [self-answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that other users can easily see that a solution was found.